# Multiple HTTP requests because of one effect and multiple actions

Tags: angular, effects, ngrx

I have two actions, `a.load` and `b.load` and off the back of them, an @effect is registered to do an HTTP call for `c`. However, the issue arises where on page load, both `a` and `b` actions are dispatched and as a result, `c` is requested for twice. The reason I need to react to both actions is because on this page, `a` or `b` can change and if so, I need the to do a request to get the new value for `c`.

Is there any way to deal with / avoid this? Maybe I could consider cancelling any previous requests inside the effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve the problem using the [`throttle` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle) - which takes a function that returns an observable and, until that observable emits, any values emitted by the source are throttled/ignored.

If you pass `throttle` the effect itself, any actions received whilst the slow request is being handled will be ignored. For example:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttle';

@Effect()
someEffect = this.actions
    .ofType(SOME_REQUEST)
    .throttle(() => this.someEffect)
    .switchMap((action) => someSlowRequest(action.payload)
        .map((result) => ({ type: SOME_RESPONSE, payload: result }))
        .catch((error) => Observable.of({ type: SOME_ERROR, payload: error }))
    );
```

If you use `throttle` in this way with your HTTP-based effect, it will see any actions that trigger the effect ignored if there is a pending HTTP request. So if that's the behaviour you are seeking, it should solve your problem.

Regarding your comment, if you want the last of the closely spaced actions to be processed, you could consider using the [`auditTime` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) - which will wait for the specified duration and will then emit the most recently received value:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/auditTime';

@Effect()
someEffect = this.actions
    .ofType(SOME_REQUEST)
    .auditTime(100)
    .switchMap((action) => someSlowRequest(action.payload)
        .map((result) => ({ type: SOME_RESPONSE, payload: result }))
        .catch((error) => Observable.of({ type: SOME_ERROR, payload: error }))
    );
```

Alternatively, you could just rely upon the `switchMap` operator - which unsubscribes when new values are received. However, my understanding is that the `ngrx` actions are dispatched synchronously, so a HTTP request is likely to be made for each action and I'm not sure how the implementation would manage their cancellation - it could be that their responses are simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, however I should have noted, I'd want the last call to be made. Could I cancel the request by unsubscribing from the request?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I need to take a look at rxjs operators 